# METAFONT: When a letter is mostly repetition of another

Tags: best-practices, metafont

I added a couple of letters to the logo font.

```
beginlogochar("C",14);
x3=leftstemloc;
x1=x5=w-x3;
x2=x4=.382[x3,x1];
top y1=h; y3=barheight; bot y5=0;
y2=y1; y4=y5;
draw z1--z2; draw z4--z5;
super_crescent(2,3,4);
labels(1,2,3,4,5); endchar;

beginlogochar("G",14);
x3=leftstemloc;
x1=x5=w-x3;
x2=x4=.382[x3,x1];
top y1=h; y3=barheight; bot y5=0;
y2=y1; y4=y5;
z6=(x5,barheight); z7=.382[z6,z3];
draw z1--z2; draw z4--z5;
super_crescent(2,3,4);
draw z5--z6--z7;
labels(1,2,3,4,5,6,7); endchar;
```

But the second is mostly repetition of the first.  What would be the
cleaner way of doing this?

(To get the example working, copy
texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/knuth-lib/logo.mf and logo10.mf, rename
them (and change the reference to the former in the latter), and add this to the former.)